# Eclipse and the SVN command line client

Tags: eclipse, svn

For a number of good reasons (I think), I find myself wanting to use the SVN command line client rather than the plugin for particular Eclipse-based Android project, and I'd like to verify some assumptions and observations I've made so far:

1. Don't check-in derivative folders such as: bin, gen, obj, and libs
2. Do check in source folders such as: assets, jni, res, and src
3. Do check in .project and .cproject configuration files

This leaves the question of what to do with .classpaths and .settings?  Although I've seen some recommend that I don't, I currently do check in .classpaths but not .settings (just discovered it - I'm an Eclipse noob).  Any advice from people who've found themselves needing to use SVN outside of Eclipse?

Comment: I think this comes down to the question of- am I keeping SVN as a source of only-what-I-need-to-build, or that plus whatever-I-might-need-to-work-on... the project. Individual prefs are generally not kept in SVN, but if you are the sole developer then it would be fine depending on how eternal your prefs are. One solution that comes to mind is to not checkin the actual dir, but to zip it, name the zip myname-prefs and check that in with the project.

Comment: You also might want to consider using Mercurial instead of SVN. Its nice.

Comment: Thanks.  I **am** the sole developer here, and find myself having to share code between 3 OS'es and 4 development platforms, and thus the SVN command line seems the simplest option since I'm spending more time on the tools than I am on the work at hand.  Learning how to use the SVN plugins for VisualStudio, Xcode and Eclipse is just too much at the moment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using similar environments (like similar Windows 7 clients where everything is installed and organized in a similar fashion) you can add project specific settings (.classpath, .settings) to version control too. However if your project is checked out in different OS'es, then most probably you would want to keep them out of versioın control.

Eclipse can guide you to what to do. Import the project into SVN by using Eclipse plugin. Then you can switch to the command line tool on prepared repository.

Comment: Thank you.  That's surely the best way to go, but I just can't dedicate any more brain cells to yet another Eclipse plugin at the moment.  I seem to have got the proper set of files checked into SVN via the command line now and can access everything now in a common manner on all three development platform (and development systems ... sigh)